# Retrieving dynamic asp.net checkbox controls - controls are added to page in repeater, but can't retrieve in postback (C#)

Tags: c#, asp.net, checkbox, controls, repeater

I have a set of checkboxes on my page that are generated using a repeater. The checkboxes are for each database in my web config, and the idea is to use them to select which databases to search. I have them generated by a repeater because I want my code to be dynamic and work in any project- therefore, database names cannot be hardcoded, and I do not have hardcoded IDs.

```
    protected void rptDatabases_OnItemDataBound(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
    {
        var databaseName = e.Item.DataItem as string;
        CheckBox checkbox = e.Item.FindControl("checkboxDatabase") as CheckBox;
        if (checkbox != null)
        {
            checkbox.Attributes["data-id"] = databaseName;
            checkbox.Text = databaseName;
        }
    }
```

---

```
<div class="databases">
    <asp:Repeater runat="server" ID="rptDatabases" OnItemDataBound="rptDatabases_OnItemDataBound">
        <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:CheckBox runat="server" ID="checkboxDatabase"/>
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:Repeater>
```

However, I can't figure out how to retrieve the data I need from them in the postback. First I tried this:

```
 public List<string> GetSelectedDatabases()
{
    var selectedDatabases = new List<string>();
    foreach (var ctrl in form1.Controls)
    {
        var checkbox = ctrl as CheckBox;
        if (checkbox != null)
        {
            if (checkbox.Checked)
            {
                selectedDatabases.Add(checkbox.Text);
            }
        }
    }
    return selectedDatabases;
}
```

but this didn't find any checkboxes, and when I stepped through, I found that it wasn't retrieving any checkbox controls at all. So I changed it from `form1.Controls` to `rptDatabases.Controls` to get the controls within the repeater. However, although this retrieves all of the checkbox controls, it is returning them as RepeaterItem objects. On this line:

```
var checkbox = ctrl as CheckBox;
```

checkbox ends up being null. I can't cast the RepeaterItem as a CheckBox, and I can't access the Text property, which I need in order to figure out which value to add.

I also tried `(var ctrl in rptDatabases.Controls.OfType<CheckBox>())` but that returns no items.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `foreach (var ctrl in form1.Controls)` you are getting all the controls on the page, but those checkboxes are in another control so that won't work.

You need to loop the `RepeaterItem` items in the Repeater and locate the checkbox within that item.

```
foreach (RepeaterItem item in rptDatabases.Items)
{
    CheckBox checkbox = item.FindControl("checkboxDatabase") as CheckBox;

    if (checkbox != null && checkbox.Checked)
    {
        selectedDatabases.Add(checkbox.Text);
    }
}
```

Comment: That's getting them, but isn't correctly returning checkbox.Checked - it's returning all of them as false

Comment: Then you probably did not wrap the databinding of the Repeater inside an IsPostBack check `if (!Page.IsPostBack) { //bind repeater here }`